# Installing mongodb-enterprise-server error

Tags: database, mongodb

**Hello guys. Can someone help me about this one? I cant install mongodb because of dependency problem. I already tried updating my linux mint terminal.**

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-enterprise-server:
 mongodb-enterprise-server depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl3 is not installed.
 mongodb-enterprise-server depends on snmp; however:
  Package snmp is not installed.

Comment: What specific version & flavour of Linux Mint are you running, what version of MongoDB are you trying to install, and what steps are you following to install? Package dependencies should normally be resolved automatically if you are installing a package that matches your O/S (or in this case, the Ubuntu release your Mint is based on).

Comment: My Linux mint version is 19.1 Tessa and wanted to install mongodb-enterprise-server-4.0.5. It is a .deb file and I only followed how I installed mongodb-compass using the command sudo dpkg -i <mongodb.deb-file>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing via `dpkg -i mongodb.deb` will not include additional package dependencies. You should be able to fix your installation by following up with `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

Unless you have strong reasons to avoid the standard process I would recommend following the tutorial to [Install MongoDB Enterprise](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-enterprise) by adding the appropriate repo definitions. Adding the normal package repo will also make it easier for you to update to newer minor releases of MongoDB 4.0.x.

Comment: Wow! Thank you mate. I followed the steps in the link and its okay now. Thanks.